# Give warning before we edit comments older than 5 minutes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, comments

If the comment is been posted more than 5 minutes before and we try to edit it, we come to know that the comments may only be edited for 5 minutes (only after once we finish editing). How about giving that warning when we click on edit button itself (or gray-out the edit button after 5 minutes). This has happened to me twice, I edited the comment, then pressed enter. The edit didn't go through and that's when I saw that the comment was posted more than 5 minutes before.

Comment: How do you handle the case when it's been 4 minutes 45 seconds and you click the button to edit, but it's more than 5 minutes when you try to post the updated comment? It's before the 5 minute limit when you start, but more than 5 minutes when you post (and therefore over the 5 minute limit)? If you're not able to get the edit in within the appropriate time frame, delete it and post a new comment.

Comment: Yes, that is one option -> delete and post a new comment. The case you mentioned is a rare one... I think what happens most of the time is that the comment is already older than 5 minutes but still there is no warning.

Comment: When the comment is more than 5 minutes old, I see that in the time stamp of the comment (as I do right this moment with my last comment, which says it was 26 mins ago). If it won't let you post your edits, *delete your old comment* and post a new one. It's not complicated, or difficult. (The other alternative is to post your comment correctly in the first place so there's less need to edit, of course.)

Comment: @KenWhite I think the OP asks about the edge case, where it's still possible to open the _comment edit window_, but being cut off to save, after you have done your edits.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes. I addressed that in my first comment. :-) (The edge case, that the OP then responded to with "No, that's a rare one.".)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just thought it would be good if we are not allowed to open the comment window altogether if it is 5+ minutes older, that's all.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar If it's 5+ mins older, you won't be able to edit directly. It's the edge case, that's actually interesting: The comment is 4:45mins old, you're going to edit, but on save the 5+min grace period for editing is reached.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh ya... the edit button disappears. That makes this entire question invalid. I should have seen at my other comments before posting this question. Ok, happens sometimes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My strategy on edge case (no more editable) comments, is to

- open the edit (as long it's still possible, within the 5min lock period)
- improve my stuff
- take a copy of everything to clipboard

Then I try to post my edits,

- if it's too late, I'm going to cancel edit, remove the former comment, and add a new one with my comments text restored from the clipboard
- otherwise my edits went through just fine

No extra feature needed!

---

The point is (opposed to just copying the text of a no more editable comment), to save all formatting and links attached you've done already in your earlier comments mini-Markdown.

Comment: I agree but too many steps involved... wouldn't it be better if the warning was given before?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar _"too many steps involved"_ What's _too many steps_ actually, but just do an additional Select All/CTRL-C to save everything, what you currently have to the clipboard?

Comment: Oh Ok... I initially (somehow) thought you copy the comment and paste it somewhere else, and then retrieve from there if the comment is not editable.

Comment: Usually the comments form a conversation thread about the answer, removing and adding again a comment breaks the flow of the conversation

Comment: it's the perfect example of a work around a bad UX